# Epigraph printing text twice when using /textit

Tags: epigraphs

```
\epigraph{
\textit{
You can only do this by mapping the territory.
By understanding how the enemy thinks and acts.
By having a solid game plan.
And by picking your battles very, very carefully.}



}%
{\textit{- Anon}\\}
```

This is my code, the epigraph prints twice when I put the text inside `\textit`.
I am not sure how to sort this issue out.

Comment: As always on this site, pleases provide a full minimal example that others can copy and test as is. For example what does this question have to do with the `biblatex` tag?

Comment: BTW: are you sure this example even compiles? I get `there's no line to end here` from those blank lines above `}%`. Never ignore compilation errors even if you get a PDF out of it. Depending on how your LaTeX is configured latex may make a choice if it encounters an error, that choice might not be any good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what causes your problem. Following is an MWE, based on the minimal code you provided, that works with no double printing.

```
% epiprob.tex  SE 584057
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\begin{document}
\epigraph{
\textit{
You can only do this by mapping the territory.
By understanding how the enemy thinks and acts.
By having a solid game plan.
And by picking your battles very, very carefully.}
%
%
%
}%
{\textit{- Anon}\\} 

\end{document}
```

If I had not removed the empty lines then a "no line to end here" was reported. Did you get that when you ran your code?